# Why Ryanair flies from both Stansted and Luton as they are very close

Tags: airline-operations, airport-operations, ryanair, airport-capacity

I am doing a research on my future trip from the United Kingdom to the Republic of Ireland and noticed Ryanair flies from both [Luton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luton_Airport) and [Stansted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_Stansted_Airport) to there. Those two airports are quite close to each other - 41 mile by road or 26 miles direct.

In my case, they do multiple daily routes to Dublin from Stansted and multiple daily from Luton as well. The price is similar.

They have a huge base in Stansted and having some unique destinations from Luton (I found at least one - to Bulgaria's Bourgas) means they break the "hub" logic - which is probably not important to them as they don't advertise or support multi-leg routes anyway, but still.

What is the point for Ryanair to fly to same destination from 2 airports located that close to each other? I would understand Stansted and [Gatwick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gatwick_Airport) as they are on 2 opposite sides of London. Could it be Stansted is getting close to its capability?

On a side note, it must be fun to fly from one to another when a need for this arises! Like a £1000 burger )).

Comment: https://commonslibrary.parliament.uk/research-briefings/cbp-9062/ Both Stansted and Luton have limited slots available.  But perhaps the real question is:  Why do people buy tickets from both airports?

Comment: When a Ryanair flight is sold out, they cannot substitute a bigger aircraft because they do not have anything outside the range 180-197 seats.  They have to schedule another flight.

Comment: So, pretty much, it is the capacity. As for why people buy - I personally consider both when plan to fly anywhere and check the package: parking price, time of flight, return flight time, if I don't drive there I might even fly from one and return to another + consider Gatwick. For me which one does not matter much - to my taste they are quite similar.

Comment: With Ryanair that would probably be a £30 burger, unless you wanted to take a bag, in which case it costs about a million pounds.

Comment: @GdD - to be fare to them, along with other discount companies they revolutionized air traveling and I personally quite like them - along with Wizz, Jet2, EasyJet and so on. 20 years ago I would not be able to buy a return ticket to Spain for £20 - and I had such trip a couple years ago. Yes, I was only allowed a hand bag, but £20? I spent more just getting to the airport and back!

Comment: @GdD As per £1000 burger joke - it is a recreational aviation joke where you fly your Cessna somewhere for fun, have a meal there - a burger :) - and when you are home that burger would be £100-£200. But yours is good as well!

Comment: I'm familiar with the $100 hamburger saying @Mykola, I've bought many of them. Or, more accurately a £200 bacon sandwitch and cuppa.

Comment: Btw it’s not just Luton-Stansted. Ryanair operate out of Manchester and Liverpool (21nm apart directly, both airports are bases). How about other close bases? E.g. Birmingham and East Midlands, Edinburgh-Glasgow (not a base)-Prestwick?

Comment: yes, this would also be of interest. It's just I did not intend to fly from there - hence had not noticed it.